# Plot 2 lines with secondary axis but don't show the first column of data

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a plot showing how 2 columns of data ('Area' and 'Vol') correspond to the first column ('Elev'). In Excel, the data and resulting chart look like this:
[image]

Here is how I tried to do this using a Pandas Dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

e = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
a = [0.0, 300.0, 375.0, 400.0, 415.0]
v = [0.0, 150.0, 487.5, 875.0, 1282.5]

geometry = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(e, a, v, )), columns=['Elev', 'Area', 'Vol'])
ax = geometry.plot(secondary_y=['Vol'])
ax.set_ylabel('Area')
ax.right_ax.set_ylabel('Vol')
```

When I execute the above code, I get this:
[image]

I don't want to show the "Elev" line because this is the independent variable represented in the x axis. How do I show this plot without the "Elev" line showing up?

In my attempt to fix this, I found this solution:

```
ax.lines[0].remove()
```

But this appears to only remove the line and not the item from the legend. Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
%matplotlib inline

e = [0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
a = [0.0, 300.0, 375.0, 400.0, 415.0]
v = [0.0, 150.0, 487.5, 875.0, 1282.5]

geometry = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(e, a, v, )), columns=['Elev', 'Area', 'Vol'])
# only plot area and vol
ax = geometry[['Area', 'Vol']].plot(secondary_y=['Vol'])
ax.set_ylabel('Area')
ax.right_ax.set_ylabel('Vol')
# set xticks to elev
ax.set_xticks(geometry['Elev'])
```

[image]

Comment: Yes that is what I needed. Thank you!